# Semantic-UI popup menu doesn't work

Tags: javascript, css, semantic-ui

I'm new in Semantic-UI and web development and I can't make the popup menu work. Actually I'm trying to create the popup menu example in [this page](http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html) and the document doesn't tell me to run any javascript etc. I've created a jsfiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/jhg9df8t/

The code is:

```
<div class="ui menu">
  <a class="browse item">
    Browse
    <i class="dropdown icon"></i>
  </a>
</div>
<div class="ui fluid popup top left transition hidden">
  <div class="ui four column relaxed equal height divided grid">
    <div class="column">
      <h4 class="ui header">Fabrics</h4>
      <div class="ui link list">
        <a class="item">Cashmere</a>
        <a class="item">Linen</a>
        <a class="item">Cotton</a>
        <a class="item">Viscose</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h4 class="ui header">Size</h4>
      <div class="ui link list">
        <a class="item">Small</a>
        <a class="item">Medium</a>
        <a class="item">Large</a>
        <a class="item">Plus Sizes</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h4 class="ui header">Colored</h4>
      <div class="ui link list">
        <a class="item">Neutrals</a>
        <a class="item">Brights</a>
        <a class="item">Pastels</a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
      <h4 class="ui header">Types</h4>
      <div class="ui link list">
        <a class="item">Knitwear</a>
        <a class="item">Outerwear</a>
        <a class="item">Pants</a>
        <a class="item">Shoes</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to initialize the popup as follows.

```
$('.example .menu .browse').popup({
inline   : true,
hoverable: true,
position : 'bottom left',
delay: {
  show: 300,
  hide: 800
 }
 });
```

This is from Popup documentation (.example class element is not included in the code you copied from semantic ui. So if you dont have that element with example class in your code I would suggest updating initialization without it). Refer to it for more information. 
http://semantic-ui.com/modules/popup.html#/examples

Also I think you might need to include JS & CSS associated with popup plugin.

If you read carefully here http://semantic-ui.com/collections/menu.html#popup-menu follow the link to popup and see if theres any additional JS and/or CSS for it.

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks man. Another question, does the `semantic.min.js` include all the javascript that I need working with Semantic UI? Or I still need to download and include separate JS files for each component?

Comment: I am not sure about it but I guess what you need is semantic js & css from here and popup js & css from here https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI/tree/master/dist/components. You can use non-min files for dev for easy read and min versions of same files on prod if applicable. lmk if it works or not by accepting answer.